# Firefox refresh in mobile view

Tags: java, jquery, firefox, jquery-mobile, struts

My company is hosting website at
http://mediadesignedu.com/

when I press ctrl+shift+m to see mobile view,not always but cant even decide when firefox keeps refreshing page.

This problem doesn't occur when I do this in google chrome.The project is running on apache tomcat struts 1.3 framework. 
Hope this information is sufficient else do not hesitate to ask for more.

Comment: So this is a Firefox question?

Comment: no this is not the problem with other projects ... the home page of this project contains image slider and such other things ... I don't know how to figure out the problem

Comment: if you feel that this is firefox problem whats the solution anyway?

Comment: No clue. Check the requests and the JavaScript.